# Função de limpeza no useEffect não está funcionando

Tags: api, react, react-native, axios, react-hooks

Olá! estou tentando cancelar a minha chamada de api utilizando o Axios  quando o componente é desemontado, e embora pareça que está sendo cancelada, ainda recebo o erro:

Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel  all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in %s.%s, a useEffect cleanup function.

Estou tentando fazer a limpeza dessa forma:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const source = axios.CancelToken.source();

    if(requestLoading){
      async function addNewUser() {
        await api.post('/api/Auth/register', {
          name,
          email,
          password
        },{
          cancelToken: source.token
        }).then(response => {
          const statusCode = response.status
          setRequestLoading(false)
          if (statusCode == 201) {
            navigation.navigate('home')
          }

        }).catch(error => {
          setRequestLoading(false)

          if(axios.isCancel(error)) {
            console.log('Request canceled')
          } else {
            setModalVisible(true)
            setApiMessage(error.response.data.errors)
            setTimeout(() => {
                setModalVisible(false)
            }, 3000)
            Vibration.vibrate(500)
          }
        }) 
      }
      addNewUser()

//FUNÇÃO DE LIMPEZA
      return () => {
        console.log('unmounting')
        setRequestLoading(false)
        source.cancel()
      }
    }
  }, [requestLoading])
```

Se alguém puder  me ajudar   a encontrar onde estou errando, agradeço muito pois sou  novo em desenvolvimento com React Native!

Comment: Não sei se é só isso, mas, quando você configurou o `array` desse `useEffects` para observar uma determinada variável e no meio do código tem a mesma atualização dessa variável ( `setRequestLoading(false)` ) ele chama novamente e cria um `loop` ... deve ser isso primeiramente falando.

Comment: Isso realmente estava errado e realizei a correção retirrando todos os `setRequestLoading(false)` de dentro do `useEffect()`. Porém o erro continua ocorrendo quando desmonto o componente. Obrigado!

Comment: Tem que analisar todos os erros, e quase impossível a gente adivinhar se puder editar sua pergunta e esclarecer melhor